# JQuery validation allow Spanish characters but no special characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to validate special characters (like @ # $ %), but allow  international (European) language characters?

I'm using [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

My current code is:

```
$('#my_form').validate({
  rules: {
    'model[field]': {
      required: true,
      noSpecialCaracters: true
    }
  }
});
```

This show errors message on typing special characters like: `ö ä å ø æ`

Comment: Please show code for your `noSpecialCaracters` additional method, there is no documentation for this method on official site. Also it seems to be spelled wrong, should it be `noSpecialCharacters` instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a custom validation method which uses Regex to validate the input allowing alphabetical letters and the special characters you defined.

```
$.validator.addMethod('customValidation',
  function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || 
  /^[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F]+$/.test(value); },
  'Bad validation message here.');
```

Comment: Whitelisting is usually a good idea, but in this case, we are talking about a whole lot of characters, not just these few.

Comment: Updated answer score :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_form').validate({
    rules: {
        'model[field]': {
        required: true,
        noSpecialCaracters:function() { return /^[0-9a-zñáéíóúü]+$/i.test(string); }
    }
});
```